# Pyplot table : Each row in 'cellColours' must have 2 columns

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors

I want to transform a dataframe into table and have the following code :

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['John','Barry','Irene','Paul','Ricky','Jenny','Tina','Linda','Toby','Peter'],
                   'Age':[19,20,17,19,18,21,19,21,18,20]})

# Create the figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Define the colors
cmap = {0:'b', 1:'y', 2:'k', 3:'gray'}
cell_colours = []
for n in range(len(df.index)):
    if n<4:
        cell_colours.append(cmap[0])
    elif 4<=n<8:
        cell_colours.append(cmap[1])
    elif 8<=n<12:
        cell_colours.append(cmap[2])
    else:
        cell_colours.append(cmap[3])

# Plot the table
table = ax.table(cellText=df.values, colLabels=df.columns, loc='center', 
                 cellColours=cell_colours)

# Add the table to the figure
fig.add_axes(ax)

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The result is

`ValueError: Each row in 'cellColours' must have 2 columns

What I'm doing wrong?
`

Answer (score 0):

It's cell colors, not row colors.  So if you have two columns, you'd need two color values per row.

For you example:

```
for n in range(len(df.index)):
    if n<4:
        cell_colours.append([cmap[0], cmap[0]])
    elif 4<=n<8:
        cell_colours.append([cmap[1], cmap[1]])
    elif 8<=n<12:
        cell_colours.append([cmap[2], cmap[2]])
    else:
        cell_colours.append([cmap[3], cmap[3]])
```

This approach allows you to have different colors for each column if you wanted.